# sub sub child node attributes according to some attribute value of child node of xml using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

i have a dropdown which consist attribute value of time node.
i want to select the sub sub child nodes attributes according to value of parent attribute

xml is as following

```
<info>
<time value="0-30">
  <id t_id="1" speaker="Rajesh "  desc="welcome" />
  <id t_id="2" speaker="Deepak "  desc="to the meeting" />
</time>
<time value="31-50">
  <id t_id="1" speaker="Vishal"  desc="welcome" />
  <id t_id="2" speaker="Vikas"  desc="to the meeting" />
</time>
</info>
```

when i select 0-30 in dropdown Rajesh and Deepak must be displayed

i am trying using linq

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select matching time element(s), and then flatten descendant id elements

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var speakers = xdoc.Descendants("time")
                   .Where(t => (string)t.Attribute("value") == "0-30")
                   .SelectMany(t => t.Descendants("id"))
                   .Select(id => (string)id.Attribute("speaker"));
```

Query syntax

```
var speakers = from t in xdoc.Descendants("time")
               where (string)t.Attribute("value") == "0-30"
               from id in t.Descendants("id")
               select (string)id.Attribute("speaker");
```

XPath

```
var speakers = from id in xdoc.XPathSelectElements("//time[@value='0-30']/id")
               select (string)id.Attribute("speaker");
```

Comment: thanx for your reply,i want to store name and desc in some string so that those values i want to bind to gridview